# Post a message as a page using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, facebook

I had successfully post a message to my own Facebook page but it was posted as a visitor(I want post as a page). I'm not sure where i missed and also i confused to the page access token.

```
 $('#btn-fb').click(function () {
                    getPageAccess(function (page_id){
                        postToFB(page_id,'sien');
                    });
                    //postStatus();
                });
function getPageAccess(callback) {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        // handle the response
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/' + page_id + '', {fields: 'access_token'}, function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    callback(page_id);
                }
            });
        }
    }, {scope: 'manage_pages,publish_pages'});
}

function postToFB(page_id, message) {
    FB.api(
            "/" + page_id + "/feed",
            "post",
            {
                "message": message
            },
    function (response) { 
        if (response && !response.error) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
        else {
        }
    }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a Page Token to post as Page, right now you are using a User Token. You are asking for the Page Token (fields parameter), but you never use it and you don´t add it as callback parameter:

```
{
    'message': message,
    'access_token': pageToken
}
```